# Trying to replace hardcoded dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying for some time to fix this issue. I am very new to sql and databases in general. So set your expectations. I have this snippet that I am trying to replace the hardcoded dates with ones that I am grabbing from a vb project.

The code in sql as it stands looks like this:

```
IF ltrim(rtrim(@RCol)) = 'I'
begin
select * from OpenQuery(MLGJSTDB, 'select count(*)
from Aroot 
inner join Acomp on acomp.PkAroot = Aroot.PkAroot and Acomp.EntryType = ''PLA'' and Acomp.Ordinal = ''001''
inner join demog on demog.pkDemog = Acomp.pkEntity
inner join Judgment on Judgment.PkAroot = Aroot.PkAroot
where Aroot.pkClient = ''CL00001O'' and upper(demog.Lastname) like ''%UHG%'' 
and JMTDate BETWEEN ''2021-04-01'' and ''2021-04-30'')
END
```

What I (in theory) want to do is:

```
IF ltrim(rtrim(@RCol)) = 'I'
begin
select * from OpenQuery(MLGJSTDB, 'select count(*)
from Aroot 
inner join Acomp on acomp.PkAroot = Aroot.PkAroot and Acomp.EntryType = ''PLA'' and Acomp.Ordinal = ''001''
inner join demog on demog.pkDemog = Acomp.pkEntity
inner join Judgment on Judgment.PkAroot = Aroot.PkAroot
where Aroot.pkClient = ''CL00001O'' and upper(demog.Lastname) like ''%UHG%'' 
and JMTDate BETWEEN '''+ @StartDate +''' and '''+ @EndDate '''')
END
```

I have been told this is an easy thing to fix but I just don't have much experience with this to know what to do.

At the top I have it looking like this if it helps:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UHG_SCORECARD] (@RCol NVARCHAR(10)= NULL, @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
AS
BEGIN
```

Comment: your try look ok  what's the issue?

Comment: Are you passing the stored procedure the correct parameters? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Obviously your query is only interested in dates - so why do you define parameters that are datetime? And why do you need to trim `@RCol`? Don't encourage lazy coders by supporting a pointless need to pass strings with random spaces prepended or appended. And if `JMTDate` is a datetime column, then your current "working" query might not do what you expect in end-of-month  edge conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the datetime format when concatenating it in the query string. You may need to convert it to varchar, which you can do like this:

```
...
JMTDate BETWEEN '''+ convert(varchar,@StartDate,23) +''' and '''+ convert(varchar,@EndDate,23) +'''' 
...
```

for more information on formats when converting dates to varchar:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15